# Upload file to API v2 of Box by Webclient

Tags: c#, box, boxapiv2

I'm working with the Box API v2, I've try to do the upload file with the WebClient but without success.

From the API:

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
-F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
-F file=@myfile.jpg
```

So I've write it by C#:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Utils.GetAccessTokenFromFile());
            client.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=-handeptrai---");
            NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection() { 
                {"attributes","{\"name\":\"test.txt\", \"parent\":{\"id\":\"0\"}}"},
                {"file",@Utils.TestFilePath}
            };
            byte[] result = client.UploadValues("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content", "POST", values);
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
        }
```

When I try to debug to see what is going on, I saw nothing at the UploadValues step.

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, finally I solved the upload problem with HttpClient and MultipartFormDataContent, here is final code to upload a text file:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Utils.GetAccessTokenFromFile());
        content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open(Utils.AnyFilePath, FileMode.Open)), "token", "test.txt");
        content.Add(new StringContent("{\"name\":\"test.txt\", \"parent\":{\"id\":\"0\"}}"), "attributes");
        var result = await client.PostAsync("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content", content);
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string sContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Then the sContent will be the json which contain details of uploaded file. Hope this help!